# Fortran Langauge Server on Windows 10

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am trying to get Visual Studio Code set up to code in Fortran. One of the Visual Studio Code extensions is Fortran Intellisense and it seems like it would be useful. It requires the [Fortran Language Server](https://github.com/hansec/fortran-language-server) to be installed on the computer.

I am having trouble determining how to install/compile this on Windows 10. I have python installed already and I've tried navigating to the folder where I extracted the repo and doing 'python fortls.exe' but the command prompt just hangs.

Could anyone please advise on how I can get this installed on Windows 10?

Comment: [Installation Instructions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hansec.fortran-ls)

Comment: Thanks although if you look that is already all in the page I linked. I DLed the repo but it doesn't contain a fortls.exe, only a fortls.py which I assume I am supposed to compile but it doesn't compile when I try from the windows command line (see above about it hanging).

Answer (score 0):

If you have python installed then fortls can be installed by running this:

```
pip install fortls
```

or `pip3 install fortls` -- since pip and pip3 should be the same (you can check by running "pip --version" and "pip3 --version".  One of those should run. Pip is python's package installer.

You do not have to download or extract the fortls repo -- pip does all the downloading and extracting to the proper place.

You can check if fortls is installed with:

```
fortls --version
```

Note that fortls is never "compiled". No code written in python is ever compiled, rather it is run by the python interpreter.